# android sqlite on application update

Tags: android, sqlite

I hava an android application which consists sqlite database in the assets folder.
In the DB I have several tables, which one of them is user data (which is updated over time by using the application - when the user installs the application this table is empty).
The other tables store data that I update.

The question is: when a user gets an updated version of my application (with sqlite database in the assets folder) from the market, I need to keep the data the user updated by using the application, but i do want to update the other tables (which consist my data).

What is the correct way to do it?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a version number for each change and implement the onUpgrade method for the possible combinations. See more in the [javadoc for SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: How do I copy the data from the DB in the new APK to the one that alreadt exists in the older application version?

Comment: You dont. You write SQL statements to insert the data in the old database as well as do update it to the new schema..

Comment: Just to check I understand correctly - lets say the table has 5,000 rows, I need to put 5,000 insert statements in my code that will be executed on the onUpgrade event?

Comment: Either that or you just do that for the user specific stuff in one database and have the database in the assests folder completely separate and just replace it on update.

Comment: I think I will go with the solution of seperating the DB`s. Do You maybe have a link explaining how to replace the existing DB with the new one?. And of course thank You very much for the help! :)

Comment: If it is located in assest with the same name it will just automatically replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said your tables are empty when the Database is first created, it shouldn't be necessary to add the Database from the `/assets`-folder.

Instead, you can use a [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), which offers an `onCreate()`-method that can do the initial table-creation (an add some example data if necessary).

If you then update your app, you simply increase the Database-version and the `onUpgrade()`-method is called, where you can then perform the Database update.

See this other question: [Run some code when user update my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121099/run-some-code-when-user-update-my-app/7121151#7121151)

If your app comes with a huge Database and inserting entry's in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` isn't the right way to go, you can still check if the Database already exists and then do the updating (through the `onUpgrade()`-method) and keep the users data.

Comment: The user`s data is empty, but the other tables already consist data when the application is first installed. That`s the data I want to replace when a new version of the application is installed.

Comment: Ho much data is changed on one update? Do you only add a few levels or do you relay need to replace the `.db`-file?